# Inserting razor syntax inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

Im trying to loop over a collection of data inside a div like this but received and error that says Unterminated string literal. Strings that start with a quotation mark (") must be terminated before the end of the line. How can i solve this?

```
 <a href="@(eventItem.Url)"   class="media-box__cover">
    @if (listingImageUrl == "") {
        if (currentCount % 2 == 0) {
         <div class="media-box__cover-image" style="background-color: #ffd205;"></div>
        }else {
         <div class="media-box__cover-image" style="background-color: #0d9430;"></div>
     }
    } else {
      <div class="media-box__cover-image" style="background-image: url('@(listingImageUrl)');"></div>
    }
</a>
```

into this,

```
for (i = 0; i < json["data"].length ; i++) {
  if(typeof(json["data"][i]) == 'object' && json["data"][i] != null){

    htmlRetStr = "<div class='block'><div class='media-boxes'>";
    htmlRetStr += "<div class='media-box'>";
    htmlRetStr += "<a href=\""+ json["data"][i]["eventUrl"] +"\" class='media-box__cover'>";
    htmlRetStr += "@if (json["data"][i]["eventUrl"] == '') { "; //error here
    htmlRetStr += "if (currentCount % 2 == 0) {";
    htmlRetStr += "<div class='media-box__cover-image' style='background-color: #ffd205;'></div>";
    htmlRetStr += "}else{";
    htmlRetStr += "<div class='media-box__cover-image' style='background-color: #0d9430;'></div> }";
    htmlRetStr += " } else {";
    htmlRetStr += "<div class='media-box__cover-image' style='background-image: url(\""+ json["data"][i]["listingImage"] +"\");'></div>} </a>";
    htmlRetStr += "<div class='media-box__main'><div class='media-box__main-inner'><div class='media-box__header'>";
    htmlRetStr += "<h3 class='media-box__heading'><a href=\""+ json["data"][i]["eventUrl"] +"\" class='media-box__heading-link'>" + json["data"][i]["heading"] + "</a></h3>";
    htmlRetStr += "<div class='media-box__meta'>Posted on: " + json["data"][i]["articleDate"] +" "+ json["data"][i]["articleMonth"] +" "+ json["data"][i]["articleYear"] + "</div></div>";
    htmlRetStr += "<p>"+ json["data"][i]["subHeading"] +"&hellip;</p>";
    htmlRetStr += "</div></div></div></div></div>";

 $("#news").append(htmlRetStr);
}
```

Comment: What you trying to achieve is not possible with this set of code. You cannot use razor syntax in a JSON response. Use JavaScript to build dynamic HTML. May I ask, what is currentCount over here? Where this has been declared and initialized?

Comment: currentCount is to count whether the image belongs to which condition. If i remove the @ if part of the code, it will return the expected output.The error only happens when i inserted the @if razor syntax.

Comment: May I ask why you have used Razor syntax here. What is your expected result you have been trying to achieve?

Comment: What im trying to achieve is to have the JavaScript to render the same html as the html block(1st part of code). Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Have a look at my answer and see if this meets your need.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. This is what i should be doing. Dont know what was i thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this would help but hope this is what you are looking for. One thing you might need to check from your end its about **currentCount**. Is this coming from JSON or from anywhere else.

```
for (i = 0; i < json["data"].length; i++) {
  if (typeof(json["data"][i]) == 'object' && json["data"][i] != null) {

    htmlRetStr = "<div class='block'><div class='media-boxes'>";
    htmlRetStr += "<div class='media-box'>";
    htmlRetStr += "<a href=\"" + json["data"][i]["eventUrl"] + "\" class='media-box__cover'>";

    if (json["data"][i]["eventUrl"] == '') {
      if (currentCount % 2 == 0) {
        htmlRetStr += "<div class='media-box__cover-image' style='background-color: #ffd205;'></div>";
      } else {
        htmlRetStr += "<div class='media-box__cover-image' style='background-color: #0d9430;'></div>";
      }
    } else {
      htmlRetStr += "<div class='media-box__cover-image' style='background-image: url(\"" + json["data"][i]["listingImage"] + "\");'></div>} </a>";
    }

    htmlRetStr += "<div class='media-box__main'><div class='media-box__main-inner'><div class='media-box__header'>";
    htmlRetStr += "<h3 class='media-box__heading'><a href=\"" + json["data"][i]["eventUrl"] + "\" class='media-box__heading-link'>" + json["data"][i]["heading"] + "</a></h3>";
    htmlRetStr += "<div class='media-box__meta'>Posted on: " + json["data"][i]["articleDate"] + " " + json["data"][i]["articleMonth"] + " " + json["data"][i]["articleYear"] + "</div></div>";
    htmlRetStr += "<p>" + json["data"][i]["subHeading"] + "&hellip;</p>";
    htmlRetStr += "</div></div></div></div></div>";

    $("#news").append(htmlRetStr);

  }
}
```